# Jenkins build health thresholds

Tags: jenkins

Is there a way to change how Jenkins computes build health based on failing tests?  I'd like Jenkins to treat *any* failing tests as something other than "sunny", but so far my searching for a way to do that has been fruitless.  Does the standard setup allow this level of control, or are there perhaps plugins that can do this?

Comment: I looked at that earlier this year, and it was hard coded in the plugins. Consider Sonar for configurable reports.

Comment: Ugh, was afraid that would be the case.  I can't tell if Sonar has any support for Ruby (our language) at all, so I guess it's a choice of either live with Jenkins as-is or build the plugins from source...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you use the [xUnit plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/xUnit+Plugin), which supports several test report formats, you can add a post-build action to parse your build's test reports and declare a build as unstable or failed depending on the number of tests that fail or are skipped.

Comment: That plugin is exactly what I was looking for - works like a charm!  Thanks!