# Jenkins build health thresholds with Allure Framework

Tags: jenkins, xunit, allure

I start using Allure Framework Plugin with Jenkins and would like to know if there is a way to mark build as successful if the number of test cases fails is under 5%. I think for this, I would need to use XUnit Plugin, but I'm wondering if anyone set it up before.

Answer (score 0):

Allure is report framework. It doesn't control your test execution and doesn't control your build status. So you can use Jenkins xUnit plugin. See [Jenkins build health thresholds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14075246/jenkins-build-health-thresholds)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Is there a way to set up xUnit so that it reads the xml files from Allure and marks build as stable?

Comment: Could you please specify test framework/allure adaptor which you are using?